# How to get top value from a inline class

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am having the following inline class

```
<DIV title="AST Infrastructure" class="ms-acal-item ms-acal-color4" style="BORDER-LEFT-WIDTH: 0px; HEIGHT: 17px; BORDER-RIGHT-WIDTH: 0px; BORDER-BOTTOM-WIDTH: 1px; POSITION: absolute; LEFT: 22px; TOP: 508px; BORDER-TOP-WIDTH: 1px; WIDTH: 1321px">
<DIV class=ms-acal-mdiv>
<A href="/Info/AS_Inf/Lists/Events/DispForm.aspx?ID=1805" target=_blank>Lorem Ipsum is a dummy text, Lorem Ipsum is a dummy text</A>
</DIV>
</DIV>
```

I need to find `Top` from inline class and i have to add 20px to top.

How to do this using  Jquery/javascript.

i can't able to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `.css('top')`:

```
 $(".ms-acal-item").css('top');
```

and for setting new value:

```
  $(".ms-acal-item").css('top',function(i,oldtop){
     return oldtop+20;
  });
```

Comment: @thanks it work, i can accept this answer in 5 minutes

Answer (score 1):

You can get css `top` property like

```
var top = $("div .ms-acal-item").css("top"); //to get top from css

//Add 20 to top variavle 
top = top + 20;
$("#scroll").css("top", top); //You can set +20 to top
```

Answer (score 0):

Get and set the top via [.css()](http://api.jquery.com/css/)

```
$(".ms-acal-item").css({top: "+=20px"});
```